# Fade one image into another using css or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I need to be able to fade in a second image above the initial image on hover. I need to make sure that **second image isn't visible initially** until it fades in. The other important note is that **neither of the images should fade out entirely** at any time. I've tried several approaches such as using 1 image, 2 images, jquery animate and css transition.

I've read that it is possible to animate a change of attribute using jquery? If this is true, how could I animate the change of 'src' in img using jquery?

```
$(".image").mouseenter(function() {
        var img = $(this);
        var newSrc = img.attr("data-hover-src");

        img.attr("src",newSrc);
        img.fadeTo('slow', 0.8, function() {
            img.attr("src", newSrc);
        });
        img.fadeTo('slow', 1);
}).mouseleave(function() {
        var img = $(this);
        var newSrc = img.attr("data-regular-src");

        img.fadeTo('slow', 0.8, function() {
            img.attr("src", newSrc);
        });
        img.fadeTo('slow', 1);
});
```

This is what i'm currently using. It's the closest i've gotten. But you can see the image change which is not desirable.

Comment: What did you try? Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: Just float two divs on top of each other and fade one on hover.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsbin.com/fepegoce/1/edit

Comment: You've mentioned that neither of the images should fade out entirely. Does that mean that at the final state there should still be a hint of the initial image and before the hover a hint of the final image? Or should there only be one image visble at the end points of the fade?

Comment: Meaning I don't want the initial image to go opacity:0, then the image changes, then the new image goes to opacity:1. I want it to be a fluid motion.

Comment: I've amended my answer and given an additional demo

Comment: I apologize, your first demo was perfect. Now im just looking for a more dynamic method of width/height on the images. Because I won't be dealing with one specific size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Using a single html element with background images**

HTML - doesn't get simpler than this

```
<div id="imgHolder"></div>
```

CSS

```
#imgHolder {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

/*Initial image*/
 #imgHolder::before {
    content:"";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-image:url(http://placehold.it/200x200);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    z-index:10;
}

#imgHolder:hover::before {
    opacity:0;
}

#imgHolder::after {
    content:"";
    background: url(http://placehold.it/200x200/FF0000);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8H46/)

**OR if you want to use image tags...**

Stealing straight from: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

HTML

```
<div id="cf">
  <img class="bottom" src="pathetoImg1.jpg" />
  <img class="top" src="pathetoImg2.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#cf {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

There are many other examples in the link as well to play with, but this will get you started.

**Final Opacity**

You've mentioned you don't want the initial image to disapear comletely. To do this change `opacity:0` to `opacity:0.5` or something similar. You'll need to experiment with that value to get the result you want.

[Demo with final opacity of 0.8](http://jsfiddle.net/u8H46/2/)

**Dynamic Image Sizes**

I think you will be stuck with the *two image* version for this if just using CSS. HTML is the same.

CSS

```
#cf {
    position:relative;
}

#cf img {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.bottom {
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}

#cf:hover img.top {
    opacity:0.8;
}

#cf:hover img.bottom {
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8H46/4/)

Comment: How would I go about doing either of these examples with a dynamic width/height? Width/height will change per image, so in most cases, the width/height won't be 200/200. Thank you for your time and examples.

Comment: So the images you are trasitioning between are different sizes?