# Loop jQuery function with fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, infinite-loop

I'm using a simple jQuery function to create a small image slider:

```
function gridhover() {
    $(".grid-item .slide-image").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(400*index).fadeIn(300);
    });
}

$( ".grid-item" ).hover(function() {
    gridhover();
});
```

If the function plays once, it stops. Is there a way to loop the function? Check out my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBvedq)!

Comment: Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793139/fade-one-image-into-another-using-css-or-jquery where he shares this great link: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cf4a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this example](http://www.simonbattersby.com/demos/crossfade_demo_basic.htm) I prepared [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/545/) for you.

```
<div id="cycler">
    <img class="active" src="image1.jpg" alt="My image" />
    <img src="image2.jpg" alt="My image" /> 
    ...
</div>
```

What he does in his example is he picks the `.active` element and looks for it's next sibling to know which one to show next. If it does not exist, it means the current active is the last one, so he takes the first one again. Simple.

I took his function and applied it to the `.hover()`. And also set the myInterval variable as global so you can access it from the `.hover()` and it's callback function.

```
var milisecs = 1000;
var myInterval;

$("#cycler").hover(function(){
    myInterval = setInterval(function(){cycleImages()}, milisecs);
}, function(){
    clearInterval(myInterval);
});
...
```

Check out the jsFiddle for the whole thing.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The idea here is that since you fadeIn something you must also fade it out and repeat the same process again and again

```
function gridhover() {
    $(".grid-item .slide-image").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(2000*index).fadeIn(300);
    });
  $(".grid-item .slide-image").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(2000*index).fadeOut(300);
    });
}
```

try this but with better timming

Comment: try increasing the delay... delay(2000*index)

Comment: in the function with the fadeout you should have them fade out with reverse order.. something like that should do it.. also you might have problem with the hover...